Jackson deserialize a json string with unknown property name into a generic type
I would like to deserialize a json string that can have an "unknown" property (but of a known generic at compile-time), and deserialize that unknown property into the supplied generic type.
The JSON string can structurally look like the following:
{
  "id":"abc",
  "human": {"name": "me", age: 99}
}
OR:
{
  "id":"abc",
  "cat": {"color": "orange"}
}
OR:
{
  "id":"abc",
  "bike": {"specs": {"speed":30}}
}

I have the following Model classes:
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Data<T> {
  String id;
  T other; // <- how can I map "cat", "human", or "bike" into this generic
}

@V/B/J
public class Human {
  String name;
  Integer age;
}

@V/B/J
public class Cat {
  String color;
}

@V/B/J
public class Bike {
  Specs specs;
}

@V/B/J
public class Specs {
  Integer speed;
}

The required generic of the JSON string will be known at compile-time, for instance:
Data<Human> humanData = objectMapper.readValue(jsonHumanString, Data.class);
Data<Cat> catData = objectMapper.readValue(jsonCatString, Data.class);
Data<Bike> bikeData = objectMapper.readValue(jsonBikeString, Data.class);

However, I still receive the error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "human". How can I forcibly map "bike", "cat", and "human" into "other"?

I think I solved my own an answer. I can use a custom deserializer on the whole Data class that resolves the generics.
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(using = GenericDeserializer.class)
public class Data<T> {
    String id;
    T other;
}

Deserializer:
public class GenericDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Data<?>> {

    public GenericDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }


    public GenericDeserializer(Class<Data<?>> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Data<?> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jsonParser);
        if (node.has("bike")) {
            return Data.<Bike>builder()
                    .id(String.valueOf(node.get("id")))
                    .other(codec.treeToValue(node.get("bike"), Bike.class))
                    .build();
        } else if (node.has("human")) {
            return Data.<Human>builder()
                    .id(String.valueOf(node.get("id")))
                    .other(codec.treeToValue(node.get("human"), Human.class))
                    .build();
        } else if (node.has("cat")) {
            return Data.<Cat>builder()
                    .id(String.valueOf(node.get("id")))
                    .other(codec.treeToValue(node.get("cat"), Cat.class))
                    .build();
        }

    }
}

